# private static final fields

Tags: java, field

I just would like to clarify this. What is the difference between -

```
private static int STUDENT_AGE = 18;
```

and

```
private static final int STUDENT_AGE = 18;
```

within the field?

Jon Skeet explained as "not related to a particular instance at all", ok I think I understand it. Then what does final do in this case exactly?

Below code does not work is it because student age is assigned as static final? Does it mean the default age can not be overwritten at all? then is it possible to create the constructor that specify an age other than the default?

```
private String myName;
private String myAddress;
private int myYearEnrolled;
private String myGender; 
private static final int STUDENT_AGE = 18; 

public Student(String name, String address, int year, String gender) {
    myName = name;
    myAddress = address;
    myYearEnrolled = year;
    myGender = gender; 
}

   public Student(int age)
{
     STUDENT_AGE = age; 
}
```

Comment: Final makes it constant. Once you declare final, you can not re-assign any value to it later.

Comment: Mabe my question was not clear enough.

Comment: @vandey it is different than a `constant` a constant's value is known at compile time.

Comment: I will add on it, No you can not set the new value from nowhere, it does not matter if it is constructor or methods

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once a variable is declared `final`, its value cannot be changed later. In the code sample you provided, a constant is declared for defining the age of a student for a particular activity. It might mean that there will be a condition where for certain activity, the age of the student will be compared with this constant. If the age of student is greater than 18, then only he will be allowed to proceed or not.

Answer (score 24):

`static` means "not related to a particular instance at all" - `final` means you cannot change this value after initialization and this value *must* be initialized.

The combination of `final` and `static` gives you the ability to create constants. This is no longer recommended in a public way (totally ok for e.g. magic numbers in a private context) as it's not typesafe. Use `Enum` post java 1.5 or create your own typesafe enums pre java 1.5 as suggested in Joshua Blochs Effective Java and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367104/enums-for-constants-in-java-is-this-good-style) question.

*Remark: reading this about a year later, I think I need to emphasize that there is nothing wrong with `public static final` fields in general, just that named constants should be implemented with `enums` or another type safe alternative.*

Answer (score 4):

```
 private static final int STUDENT_AGE = 18;
```

It's constant declaration. You can't change the value.

```
private static int STUDENT_AGE = 18;
```

It's a static declaration but not constant. The value can be changed.

Comment: It's not a constant, the difference is a constant's value is known at compile time.  Java does not support constants, it mimics it by using `static final...`

Comment: though Java has `const` keyword but it is reserved. :(

Comment: Well, java has enums which are constants on steroids. Java lacks support for constness, however.

Comment: So private static final int STUDENT_AGE = 18; means students age will always be 18 years old unless I get lid of "final" is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

`final` variables can only be initialized once.

Answer (score 1):

The `final` modifier on a field signifies that the field's value *cannot* be modified once initialized.

Because of this, you cannot set `STUDENT_AGE = age;` unless it's non-final.

Answer (score 1):

To simply say, the modifier final means its FINAL. you can not change the value once its defined.

And coming to your requirement, if you want to provide default age if nothing is provided, then simply remove final modifier for the variable STUDENT_AGE. just what @Quoi said

Answer (score -1):

`final static` variables can only be initialized once, but not necessarily at the time of declaration.. But once it is initialized, it's value cannot be changed.. So, you can initialize your `final static` variable, at the time of declaration or in static block.

```
private static final int STUDENT_AGE = 20;
```

or

```
private static final int STUDENT_AGE;
static {
      STUDENT_AGE = 20;
}
```

Now, a `static` variable (also called, `class` variable), is not specific to any instance. It is shared among all the instances of that class..

See this way, `Static` variables are loaded into memory when the class is first time loaded.. That's why it is shared by all the instances. So any change in static variable by any instance will be reflected to all other instances of that class (Yes, you read that right.. You can access `static` variables through instance variable of the class also.. But compiler is ultimately worried about the actual class only)

Comment: You cannot assign a value after initialization to a `final` variable. In your second example, `STUDENT_AGE` is given the default value of `0` (if it were allowed to compile, which it wouldn't due to `STUDENT_AGE = 20;`.).