# Why should data fields be static and final

Tags: java, static, final

Deitel's How To Program Java book says:

> A final field should also be declared static if it is initialized in its declaration to a value.

Why is that?

```
public class A
{
   private final int x = 5;
   private static final int y = 5;
}
```

I think x and y are the same.
What does the `static` qualifier matter here?
What is the advantage of the `static` qualifier up there for software engineering observation?

Comment: `static` simply means you don't need a class instance to be able to reference it. I'm not sure I entirely agree with the statement, but it is taken out of context, as you could have a `final` field which is initialised from a value passed to the class's constructor, but maybe that's a different use-case

Comment: that is right, is this the only difference?

Comment: *"A final field should also be declared static if it is initialised in its declaration to a value."* Who ever wrote that should differ between mutable and immutable types.

Comment: They aren't the same. For n `A`s there are n `x`s and only 1 `y`.

Comment: I would suggest the only other (significant) difference is how memory is allocated for them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [private static final fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801223/private-static-final-fields)

Comment: `x` is a constant expression, but `this.x` is not... glitch in the spec (and compilers). see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/java-lang-fans/AyS3UqX4lj4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` is an instance variable while `y` is global.

What does that mean?

Let's look at this example:

```
public class A {
    public A() {
        System.out.println("create A");
    }
}

public class B {
    public B() {
        System.out.println("create B");
    }
}

public class C {
    private static B b = new B();
    private A a = new A();
}
```

Then a main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    C c1 = new C();
    C c2 = new C();
}
```

Which prints:

```
> create B
> create A
> create A
```

`c1` and `c2` shares the same instance of `B` while they both create their own instance of `A`!

So `c1.b == c2.b` while `c1.a != c2.a`.

So summary: 
there is only one and the same place/address for field b for every instance of class C (c1, c2)
but for field a there are different places/addresses in the different instances.

The example is a bit oversized with class A and B:
Even for simple fields (int, float, ...) is one and the same place/occurrence for a static field in every instance of a class.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is final, it will always hold the same value.
If you don't declare it `static`, you will create one variable for each instance of your class. Being `static` means you declare the variable only once, avoiding unnecessary memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a variable as static is more memory effecient. In your example for instance, no matter how many times you create a `new A()`, because fields `x` and fields `y` have been declared static, they will only be allocated memory once. If you do not declare them as `static`, they will be allocated memory with every new class instance.

It is sensible to declare a `final` variable that has been initialized like yours as static because it is not able to change, and thus allocating it memory just one time is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, it's to save memory. If the constant is always the same no matter what, then you might as well make it static so that it doesn't get created for each object. You **don't** want to make it static, however, if the constant is not necessarily the same for each object (for example, if your constant is initialized somewhere in a constructor).

Comment: *"if your constant is initialized somewhere in a constructor"* Then it isn't a _constant_ anymore

Comment: Well, it's not constant across all objects, but it _is_ constant for the object after initialization (its value can't be changed).

Answer (score 1):

It saves memory as it only allocates for 1 copy of the variable. If you were to make a new instance for a non-static variable for it will make a new copy for that specified instance.

Since they are final they cannot be changed so it would make sense to make them static, so when you make new instances, nothing new is allocated for the variables since they can't even be altered.