# Right way to make static constants

Tags: java

I don't know, what do you think is the best (or most recognized) way of declaring group of constants?

Usually, I create a static class called Constants and lets say I expect an object to be either type_a or type_b or type_c. What would be right way?

```
public class Constants{
          public static enum TYPE{ A, B, C};
}

public class Constants{
          public static int TYPE_A = 0;
          public static int TYPE_B = 1;
          public static int TYPE_C = 2;
}

public class Constants{
          public static int type[] = new int {"A", "B", "C"};
}

public class Constants{
          public class Type{
                 public static int A = 0;
                 public static int B = 1;
                 public static int C = 2;
          }
}
```

What do you say?

Thanks

Comment: are these constant called by many classes?

Comment: Why have the class at all? Why not *just* the enum?

Comment: `enum` will be my choice

Comment: `enum`s are highly underrated in java. They are thread-safe, allow creating your own methods while ensuring constant nature of variables and provide a built-in API for various useful features. +1 for enum :)

Comment: The only constants here are the enum values. Everything else is read/write. You need to use 'final'.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote... very valid questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can have `interface` which contains constants but it's a damn antipattern.
- You can have `class` which contains constant and you can use `MyClass.constant` to access value but that's again an antipattern.

Now Solution to above antipatterns is Use of `static import` which is proper to work with in this scenario.

- Third one and my favorite one is `Enum` which provides many interesting thing the most important is `ThreadSafety`. So consider this as a suggestion.

Some benefits of `Enum`

- ThreadSafety
- Enumerated constants makes code much more readable.
- Type Safe
- Ordered etc.

For The Reason **Why?**:

[Should you always use enums instead of constants in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367104/should-you-always-use-enums-instead-of-constants-in-java)

Comment: Thank you, the only reason I am hesitants for enum i that if I want to pass the enum value as an id (lets say over network) then I send its index as ordinal and then I have to convert the enum to array at the receiving end so I can access the num using ordinal

Comment: @Snake you shouldn't use the `ordinal()` method (that's another bad practice!), you simply send the enum (over the network) - after all it's serializable

Comment: How can I loop over all the enums? I mean let's say the user gives me a value ( and the possible values match the enum), So I want to compare so that I can store the value as enum

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can create constants in two ways
1. using static final modifier before a variable as

```
public static final int CONSTANT = 100;
```

Now if many classes access this, you can declare it inside an interface.
2. The second option is to use an enum. I prefer this one as it has a number of advantages. You can have constructors and methods and also have in-built API to carry out a number of things. Also they are thread-safe. So I will recommend enum.

Answer (score -1):

I usually just do `public static final int FOO = 42` for my constants.

If I have more than one class and the constants are in the Bar class, I can access them from any class with `Bar.FOO` (even from outside the package if I import or use the fully qualified name).

Comment: -1 don't brag about bad habits...

Comment: Care to back up your reasoning for it being a bad habit instead of just coming off as rude? Why is it bad to do it that way?

Comment: From *Effective Java* by Bloch: [Item 30: Use enums instead of int constants](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=Item+30:+Use+enums+instead+of+int+constants&source=bl&ots=yZClRkn_TY&sig=CJt4F1TJRWlAz_oL7oxLGVWDUI4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KoLcU-yzO6iCiwKMxYDIDA&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Item%2030%3A%20Use%20enums%20instead%20of%20int%20constants&f=false).  (By the way, this book is a "must" if you want to become a good Java developer)